# Check if logged in main domain in single wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two domains mapped in a single installation.
The main problem is if I access the website with the second domain, the user won't be logged in the website. That's a fact, I can't do it due to security problem.

So I was thinking of redirecting the user to the main domain if he is logged. **But the problem is still the same**. I can't detect if he is logged in the main domain because we access by the second domain.

By accessing the website by the second domain, is there a way to detect if he is logged in the first domain ?

This is what I have to detect if user is logged in in my wordpress :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
```

So basically :
if access website by domain2.com, check if logged in domain1.com.
domain2.com is mapped to domain1.com

Answer (score 0):

Two domains pointing to one page, isn't this going to result in duplicate content?

I would propose to select the main domain (eg. domain1.com) and to use the second domain (eg. domain2.com) to redirect to domain1.com.

It will solve your problem because you'll be always using just one domain and the won't be any duplicate content.

Comment: No, I really want to check if I am logged in the first domain